# I want to refresh a ListView when search item is selected from dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen as soon as i navigate to this screen from previous screen i fetchs data from server according to selected location. For this i call getData() method in initState() method.
On this Screen i have a searchbar on top which shows dropdown list of locations, and below i have a listview which shows data according to choosen location.
Now I want to refresh listView when a user selects any location from dropdown list from search bar. I'm stuck how can i call my getData() method again when selected loation changed.
[image].

```
  class SearchResultPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final TypeAheadModel selectedLocation;
  SearchResultPage(this.selectedLocation);

  @override
  _SearchResultPageState createState() => _SearchResultPageState();
}

class _SearchResultPageState extends State<SearchResultPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SearchResultPage> {
  late ScrollController _scrollController;
  late FoodSearchViewModel viewModel;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
    viewModel = FoodSearchViewModel();
    getData(widget.selectedLocation);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(SearchResultPage oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  Future<List<DishModel>> getData(TypeAheadModel typeAheadModel) async {
    if (!viewModel.isLoading) {
      setState(() {
        viewModel.isLoading = true;
      });
      var result = await viewModel.getData(widget.selectedLocation);
      setState(() {
        if (result.isEmpty || result.length == viewModel.totalCount) {
          viewModel.hasLoadMore = false;
        }
        viewModel.isLoading = false;
        viewModel.showShimmer = false;
      });
    }
    return viewModel.foodList;
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    loadMore();
  }

  Future<List<DishModel>> loadMore() async {
    if (!viewModel.isLoading) {
      if (_scrollController.position.extentAfter < 150) {
        setState(() {
          viewModel.isLoading = true;
        });
        var moreItems = await viewModel.loadMore(widget.selectedLocation);
        setState(() {
          if (moreItems.isEmpty ||
              viewModel.foodList.length == viewModel.totalCount) {
            viewModel.hasLoadMore = false;
          }
          viewModel.isLoading = false;
        });
      }
      return viewModel.foodList;
    }
    return viewModel.foodList;
  }

  final brandId = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (Navigator.of(context).userGestureInProgress)
          return false;
        else
          return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
        body: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: viewModel.showShimmer
                ? 5
                : (viewModel.hasLoadMore
                    ? viewModel.foodList.length + 1
                    : viewModel.foodList.length),
            controller: _scrollController,
            cacheExtent: 9999,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              print(index);
              if (!viewModel.showShimmer &&
                  viewModel.hasLoadMore &&
                  index >= viewModel.foodList.length) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: const Center(child: CupertinoActivityIndicator()),
                );
              } else {
                if (viewModel.showShimmer) {
                  return buildShimmer();
                } else {
                  return DishTile(
                      dishNameTextStyle: titleTextStyle,
                      textStyle: subtitleTextStyle,
                      dish: viewModel.foodList[index]);
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildShimmer() => Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 140,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            ShimmerWidget.rectangular(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .45,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8, right: 8),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ShimmerWidget.rectangular(height: 10),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      ShimmerWidget.rectangular(
                        height: 8,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .30,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 6,
                      ),
                      ShimmerWidget.rectangular(
                        height: 8,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .20,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to give any concrete example since your code is not executable but the basic idea is: use `didUpdateWidget`:

```dart
@override
void didUpdateWidget(SearchResultPage oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  getData(widget.selectedLocation);
}
```

I see you already had `didUpdateWidget` so maybe you had an error trying to do this? If so please share the error.

Comment: Yes, I already had tried this approach and it was working also, but another issue i got when i called  getData(widget.selectedLocation) from didUpdateWidget(SearchResultPage oldWidget) is that whenever soft keyboard open/close, didUpdateWidget method executes, therefore unnecessarily getData() called and ui refreshed.